# Issue Installing Rails on MAC --> development tools installed --> mkmf.log warnings . Please Assist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, macos, homebrew, ruby-development-tools

I have reset my mac recently. Rails won't install
I typed

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I receive this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  

> Check the mkmf.log file for more details.

  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:14:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r/gem_make.out
```

When I check the mkmf.log file it says:

```
have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lz... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lz  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'deflateReset'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lz  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'deflateReset' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
              ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -llibz... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -llibz  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'deflateReset'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -llibz  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'deflateReset' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
              ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib1... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzlib1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'deflateReset'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzlib1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'deflateReset' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
              ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzlib  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'deflateReset'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzlib  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'deflateReset' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
              ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzdll... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzdll  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'deflateReset'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzdll  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'deflateReset' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
              ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzlibwapi... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzlibwapi  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'deflateReset'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return 0; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/zlib  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wextra-tokens  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector          -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lzlibwapi  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'deflateReset' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
              ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

Failed to configure zlib. It will not be installed.
```

I'm not sure what is going on and I need to get a Rails project started.

What I've tried:

1. Making sure xcode was installed
2. Deleting and reinstalling Ruby
3. Software Update --> up-to-date
4. reinstalling rvm
5. Yelling at Screen
6. Taking Shots from Frosted ShotGlass

Comment: Can you try using RBENV https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its likely because of not having your default ruby-version defined,
Try these:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install ruby-2.6
rvm use ruby-2.6.3
rvm --default use 2.6.3
```

Just replace the version you want instead of `2.6.3`

Comment: you are the GOAT for this  ..Thanks this Worked 